# Problem with deploying IN-MEMORY db table changes with existing SCHEMABINDING dependencies

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, in-memory-database, dacpac, sqlpackage

We have many automated deploys of in-memory and *regular* databases. Build produces dacpac, then **SqlPackage.exe** performs deploy. Recently we've faced an issue when tried to add new column to the table in IN-MEMORY database. There was a function dependent on this table, of course with both **NATIVE_COMPILATION** and **SCHEMABINDING** options set.

SqlPackage solved SCHEMABINDING lock on a table as it would do for a regular database and non-natively compiled function - it generated deploy script with these steps:

1. alter the function to remove SCHEMABINDING option (but keep NATIVE_COMPILATION option)
2. alter the table
3. alter the function back with SCHEMABINDING.

And this deployment fails. Because **NATIVE_COMPILATION** function requires **SCHEMABINDING** option and generated deployment script is a priori invalid in this part.

I've registered a [bug fix request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/5b4e718a-a0d3-ed11-a81c-000d3ae51e62). Asking here if anyone has a workaround or knows how to fix this. Currently we "fix" such issues with manual pre-deployment script which drops all blocking dependencies, then the deploy restores such functions. And it does not smell good.

Example of generated deployment script part (obfuscated):

```
GO
PRINT N'Removing schema binding from [my].[fn]...';

GO
ALTER FUNCTION my.fn
(@bar INT NULL)
RETURNS TABLE 
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION -- this is an illegal set of options
AS
RETURN 
    SELECT t.id
    FROM dbo.altered_table AS t
    WHERE t.foo = @bar
GO
PRINT N'Altering Table dbo.altered_table...';
 
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.altered_table
    ADD new_col INT NULL;

GO
PRINT N'Adding schema binding to my.fn...';

GO
ALTER FUNCTION my.fn
(@bar INT NULL)
RETURNS TABLE 
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN 
    SELECT t.id
    FROM dbo.altered_table AS t
    WHERE t.foo = @bar
GO
```

SqlPackage.exe version: 16.0.5400.1
SqlServer version: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU19) (KB5023049) - 15.0.4298.1 (X64)
Target database compatibility level: 150
Standalone server (not azure)

upd

SqlPackage 162.0.52 also has this bug

Comment: Bug report https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx/issues/308 Fix is expected in 162.2 release